# Market Share Points of Linux Server Distributions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, linux-distributions, linux-server

Which distribution does have best market share rates?

Is it still CentOS?
I'm guessing Ubuntu server has already overtaken others. But I'm not sure.

Is there a reliable document about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian is now the leading Linux distribution being used. Debian and Ubuntu have gained market share and have overtaken CentOS. More details can be found here - http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/os-linux/all/all

Comment: these are only web servers and only top 1 million websites as per the site. It is very hard to judge- I think Debian is number one

Comment: since most market surveys tend to rely on which OS ships with the market, it might be difficult to get exact numbers on linux distro. In that case, web servers might be the best sample available.

Comment: yes, web server could be one to measure this. By the way, do you know when the document was written? I can't find it. It is much more important thing.

Comment: I think it is a continually updated statistic. The dates on the graphs seem to indicate that.

Comment: Wow, Ubuntu is still 10%? Very surprise :) Thanks anyway.